# Password Encryption Outdated

Tags: php, encryption

I have this code that encrypts a users password and turns it into an integer string but the code itself only works on PHP 5.6 and I'm wanting to be able to update to a more recent version of PHP but anytime I try to use an updated version this code stops working by that it outputs the wrong encryption. The script is used to encrypt a users password for an old game and that's the only way the game can read the user's login information is what that integer that is made.

This is the code that is used to encrypt the user's password, the last $dwVal is the final output for the encryption.

Has anyone seen a code like this before or know what it is or if its possible to get this updated so it can work on an updated version of PHP.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$arrCrc = array(0x00000000,0x04C11DB7,0x09823B6E,0x0D4326D9,0x130476DC,0x17C56B6B,0x1A864DB2,0x1E475005,0x2608EDB8,0x22C9F00F,0x2F8AD6D6,0x2B4BCB61,0x350C9B64,0x31CD86D3,0x3C8EA00A,0x384FBDBD,0x4C11DB70,0x48D0C6C7,0x4593E01E,0x4152FDA9,0x5F15ADAC,0x5BD4B01B,0x569796C2,0x52568B75,0x6A1936C8,0x6ED82B7F,0x639B0DA6,0x675A1011,0x791D4014,0x7DDC5DA3,0x709F7B7A,0x745E66CD,0x9823B6E0,0x9CE2AB57,0x91A18D8E,0x95609039,0x8B27C03C,0x8FE6DD8B,0x82A5FB52,0x8664E6E5,0xBE2B5B58,0xBAEA46EF,0xB7A96036,0xB3687D81,0xAD2F2D84,0xA9EE3033,0xA4AD16EA,0xA06C0B5D,0xD4326D90,0xD0F37027,0xDDB056FE,0xD9714B49,0xC7361B4C,0xC3F706FB,0xCEB42022,0xCA753D95,0xF23A8028,0xF6FB9D9F,0xFBB8BB46,0xFF79A6F1,0xE13EF6F4,0xE5FFEB43,0xE8BCCD9A,0xEC7DD02D,0x34867077,0x30476DC0,0x3D044B19,0x39C556AE,0x278206AB,0x23431B1C,0x2E003DC5,0x2AC12072,0x128E9DCF,0x164F8078,0x1B0CA6A1,0x1FCDBB16,0x018AEB13,0x054BF6A4,0x0808D07D,0x0CC9CDCA,0x7897AB07,0x7C56B6B0,0x71159069,0x75D48DDE,0x6B93DDDB,0x6F52C06C,0x6211E6B5,0x66D0FB02,0x5E9F46BF,0x5A5E5B08,0x571D7DD1,0x53DC6066,0x4D9B3063,0x495A2DD4,0x44190B0D,0x40D816BA,0xACA5C697,0xA864DB20,0xA527FDF9,0xA1E6E04E,0xBFA1B04B,0xBB60ADFC,0xB6238B25,0xB2E29692,0x8AAD2B2F,0x8E6C3698,0x832F1041,0x87EE0DF6,0x99A95DF3,0x9D684044,0x902B669D,0x94EA7B2A,0xE0B41DE7,0xE4750050,0xE9362689,0xEDF73B3E,0xF3B06B3B,0xF771768C,0xFA325055,0xFEF34DE2,0xC6BCF05F,0xC27DEDE8,0xCF3ECB31,0xCBFFD686,0xD5B88683,0xD1799B34,0xDC3ABDED,0xD8FBA05A,0x690CE0EE,0x6DCDFD59,0x608EDB80,0x644FC637,0x7A089632,0x7EC98B85,0x738AAD5C,0x774BB0EB,0x4F040D56,0x4BC510E1,0x46863638,0x42472B8F,0x5C007B8A,0x58C1663D,0x558240E4,0x51435D53,0x251D3B9E,0x21DC2629,0x2C9F00F0,0x285E1D47,0x36194D42,0x32D850F5,0x3F9B762C,0x3B5A6B9B,0x0315D626,0x07D4CB91,0x0A97ED48,0x0E56F0FF,0x1011A0FA,0x14D0BD4D,0x19939B94,0x1D528623,0xF12F560E,0xF5EE4BB9,0xF8AD6D60,0xFC6C70D7,0xE22B20D2,0xE6EA3D65,0xEBA91BBC,0xEF68060B,0xD727BBB6,0xD3E6A601,0xDEA580D8,0xDA649D6F,0xC423CD6A,0xC0E2D0DD,0xCDA1F604,0xC960EBB3,0xBD3E8D7E,0xB9FF90C9,0xB4BCB610,0xB07DABA7,0xAE3AFBA2,0xAAFBE615,0xA7B8C0CC,0xA379DD7B,0x9B3660C6,0x9FF77D71,0x92B45BA8,0x9675461F,0x8832161A,0x8CF30BAD,0x81B02D74,0x857130C3,0x5D8A9099,0x594B8D2E,0x5408ABF7,0x50C9B640,0x4E8EE645,0x4A4FFBF2,0x470CDD2B,0x43CDC09C,0x7B827D21,0x7F436096,0x7200464F,0x76C15BF8,0x68860BFD,0x6C47164A,0x61043093,0x65C52D24,0x119B4BE9,0x155A565E,0x18197087,0x1CD86D30,0x029F3D35,0x065E2082,0x0B1D065B,0x0FDC1BEC,0x3793A651,0x3352BBE6,0x3E119D3F,0x3AD08088,0x2497D08D,0x2056CD3A,0x2D15EBE3,0x29D4F654,0xC5A92679,0xC1683BCE,0xCC2B1D17,0xC8EA00A0,0xD6AD50A5,0xD26C4D12,0xDF2F6BCB,0xDBEE767C,0xE3A1CBC1,0xE760D676,0xEA23F0AF,0xEEE2ED18,0xF0A5BD1D,0xF464A0AA,0xF9278673,0xFDE69BC4,0x89B8FD09,0x8D79E0BE,0x803AC667,0x84FBDBD0,0x9ABC8BD5,0x9E7D9662,0x933EB0BB,0x97FFAD0C,0xAFB010B1,0xAB710D06,0xA6322BDF,0xA2F33668,0xBCB4666D,0xB8757BDA,0xB5365D03,0xB1F740B4);
$PassCrc = $pass1;
$dwVal = 0;
$LenPass = strlen($PassCrc);

if ($LenPass <= 4)
{
$j = 24;
$temp = substr($PassCrc, 0, 1);
$temp = ord($temp);
$dwVal = $temp << $j;
for ($i = 0; $i < $LenPass - 1; $i++)
{
$j = $j - 8;
$temp = substr($PassCrc, $i + 1, 1);
$temp = ord($temp);
$temp <<= $j;
$dwVal = $dwVal | $temp;
}

$dwVal = ~ $dwVal;
}
  else
{
$j = 24;
$temp = substr($PassCrc, 0, 1);
$temp = ord($temp);
$dwVal = $temp << $j;
for ($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++)
{
$j = $j - 8;
$temp = substr($PassCrc, $i, 1);
$temp = ord($temp);
$temp <<= $j;
$dwVal = $dwVal | $temp;
}
$dwVal = ~ $dwVal;
$dwVal = dechex($dwVal);
$dwVal = hexdec($dwVal);
$tmpChar = substr($PassCrc, 4);
$count = strlen($tmpChar);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
$dwValTemp = $dwVal;
$dwValTemp <<= 8;
$temp = substr($tmpChar, $i, 1);
$temp = ord($temp);
$dwTemp = $dwValTemp | $temp;
$dwTemp = dechex($dwTemp);
$dwTemp = hexdec($dwTemp);
$dwVal = $dwVal / pow(2, 24);
$dwVal = intval($dwVal);
$dwVal = $dwTemp ^ $arrCrc[$dwVal];
$dwVal = dechex($dwVal);
$dwVal = hexdec($dwVal);
}
}
$dwVal = ~ $dwVal;
$dwVal = dechex($dwVal);
$dwVal = hexdec($dwVal);
```

Comment: "stops working" isn't a very useful description.  Have you stepped through each line in an environment that works and an environment that doesn't work to figure out which line is different?  More information needed.

Comment: It works but the output changes into different integer and the password for login no longer works.

Comment: Cool okay so what happened when you did what I suggested?  At which line does the output first differ?  You've debugged the code right?

Comment: So looks like I get an error at $dwVal  = $dwTemp ^ $arrCrc[$dwVal]; Notice: Undefined offset: 1099511627726.

Normal variables output as below:
LenPass: 6
Count: 2
j: 0
temp: 54
PassCrc: 123456
dwValTemp: -923032064
tmpChar: 56
dwTemp: 3371935286
dwVal: 4079457443

When changed to 7.1 I get the follow:

LenPass: 6
Count: 2
j: 0
temp: 54
PassCrc: 123456
dwValTemp: -54091623432192
tmpChar: 56
dwTemp: 1.8446689982086E+19
dwVal: 54091623432191

Comment: I believe the issue is with the caret in the line  $dwVal  = $dwTemp ^ $arrCrc[$dwVal];

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, this is a mess.  It's seemingly a custom implementation of a hashing mechanism.  I'd recommend ditching it entirely and forcing users through a re-validation of their accounts.

Establish a new process for hashing passwords (I'd encourage you to use [PHP's Password Hashing Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php)).  Then either clear out passwords in the database, or establish a "flag" to determine whether users have logged in yet, under the new process.  If they haven't, don't try to perform a username and password validation.  Rather, validate it's a valid username, and initiate an email they must confirm to validate ownership of the account.  Upon validation, have them set a new password, and use your new process to store it.

This way any subsequent logins thereafter just need to use your predefined process.

Comment: It's not possible for me to change the login coding for the login server and it uses the same process to read the password inputted and then encrypted it and check it to match the database. My only option would be to leave it as it is and continue to use PHP 5.6.

Comment: I would love to be able to use something more updated but I just don't have the ability to be able to change it. If anything I'm trying to figure out what type of encryption it even is using cause I've not been able to find anything similar to it.

Comment: If you can't change it, then isn't this entire thread a moot point?

Comment: I can change/update the php code, I just have to be able to get the correct output as I would on 5.6.

Comment: Right, so my suggestion is still valid.  Circumvent this bit of PHP code, and perform a reset on how passwords are stored in your database.

Comment: Your suggestion isn't valid. I'm not able to change the process of how the login server reads the password on the database. It processes the string the same as the php script does to get the same output to check that it matches what is in the database.

Comment: OK, I'll try this one more time before giving up on this.  Bypass that in its entirety; subvent it.  You have a database, and in it you presumably have data such as usernames and email addresses.  Clear all password hashes from your database.  Then reconfigure the logic of logging in to look for an empty password field.  If it's found, don't try to verify the password the user submitted.  Instead, force them into verifying their account via email, and then, upon verification, allow them to "reset" their password.  This reset would take place using whatever hashing algorithm you choose to use.

Comment: Thus any logins taking place where a password hash exists, would be those who have already reset, and you can log them in normally.  You can gracefully ditch this archaic password function if you just start the process intelligently.